# `apiRevision` flag isn't working in Bicep template

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I am using Bicep to deploy open api json into Azure API Management. The snippet looks like this.

```
resource fuseintegrationsapi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-08-01' = {
  name: '${apim.name}/integrations-api-${environment_name}'
  properties: {
    description: 'Contains integrations apis used to control the platform.'
    type: 'http'
    apiRevision: '1234'
    isCurrent: true
    subscriptionRequired: false
    displayName: 'Integrations Api'
    serviceUrl: '${api_backend_url}/api/test/v1/integrations'
    path: '${environment_name}/api/test/v1/integrations'
    protocols: [
      protocol
    ]
    value: api_link
    format: 'openapi+json-link'

    apiType: 'http'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    api2
  ]
  resource symbolicname 'policies' = {
    name: 'policy'
    properties: {
      value: anonymous_operation_policy
      format: 'rawxml'
    }
  }
}
```

Even though revision is hardcoded to `1234` it's always using default `1` and the API is not updating with latest open api specification.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured out that you have to put the revision in the name also.

```
name: '${apim.name}/integrations-api-${environment_name};rev=1234'
```